# why do i get Error installing cocoapods every time?

Tags: flutter, macos, terminal, cocoapods, macbookpro

Trying to work download flutter on mac ,and when i run flutter doctor i get error  at xcode that says **CocoaPods not installed**

so i tried downloading it with **`"sudo gem install cocoapods"`**
and i get this error

```
Error installing cocoapods:
    There are no versions of cocoapods-downloader (>= 2.0) compatible with your Ruby & RubyGems. Maybe try installing an older version of the gem you're looking for?
    cocoapods-downloader requires Ruby version >= 2.7.4. The current ruby version is 2.6.10.210.
```

What can I do?

Installing cocoapods
i expected it work

Comment: Update your ruby version

Answer (score 0):

In my case it helped:

```
brew install cocoapods
```

and

```
brew link cocoapods
```